# Typing Persian in `CMD`

Tags: encoding, cmd, windows-10

I want to code in `Python`.
My code has Persian interface but when i run it in CMD ,I see just question marks `?` , I also tried `chcp 65001` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please give us a [Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Change `cmd` window font. Question marks are replacements for that glyphs  which are not present in the current Windows console font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but i solved changing the font on properties of Command Prompt. Select a proper font that fits your desired languages.

Comment: Thanks, **Courier New Font** worked for me.

Comment: how did you choose the font in cmd? i only see 3 fonts available there!

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of searching on Google, and using the several website's codes, I was able to find a code that solves this problem to some extent:

1. You must first install the Bi Directional library in Python. By installing this library, Letter layout Is corrected. But the letters are still separate.
2. download the Better-Arabic-Reshaper library from GitHub and install it in Python to fix the problem
3. then add this code to your project:

   ```
   import arabic_reshaper
   from bidi.algorithm import get_display 
   import shutil
   from os import system
   system('chcp 1256')
   system('cls')
   def farsi_print(txt):
       columns=shutil.get_terminal_size((80, 20)).columns
       txt2=[]
       txt3=''
       for n in txt:
           if n!="\n":
               txt3+=n
           else:
               txt2.append(txt3)
               txt3=''
       txt2.append(txt3)
       txt3=''
       for line in txt2:
           reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(line)
           bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
           bidi_text = bidi_text.rjust(columns-1)
           print(bidi_text)
   ```
4. Use `farsi_print()` To write in Persian in cmd!

Comment: The result was unaligned and messy But thanks for your script.